# Android Permissions and Explanations

Tags: android, permissions

I am doing some research on Android permissions and whether or not they could abuse data privacy. Does anyone have a good source on all updated Android permissions with a short explanation on what each one can do?

Answer (score 2):

Ask, and it shall be delivered: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

All items on this very large list are arguments to [<uses-permission>](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestUsesPermission) in the Android Manifest. It would also be helpful to read these as well:

- [How permissions are used by the Android system](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html):

> At application install time, permissions requested by the application are granted to it by the package installer, based on checks against the signatures of the applications declaring those permissions and/or interaction with the user. No checks with the user are done while an application is running; the app is either granted a particular permission when installed, and can use that feature as desired, or the permission is not granted and any attempt to use the feature fails without prompting the user.

- [How Android implements security](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/implement.html)
- [The Manifest groups for permissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group.html)